# How to get cart items by customer id/email at the admin side in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, admin, cart

I need to display a grid in the admin side with the list of cart products which is not yet ordered for all the customers. ie I want to display quote items of customer. I tried below code, but the results returns something not related to right.

```
$customer_email = 'rasd@gmail.com'; 
    $customer_detail = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer_detail->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
    $customer_detail->loadByEmail($customer_email);

    $storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())->getStoreIds(); 
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)->loadByCustomer($customer_detail);
     if ($quote) { 
        $collection = $quote->getItemsCollection();
        if($customer_email == 'rasd@gmail.com') {   
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($collection->getData());        
        }
        if ($collection->count() > 0) { echo $customer_email; die('here');
            foreach( $collection as $item ) {
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($item->getData());
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
$collection->getData() - it returns the result array but that one seems wrong.
$item->getData() - No result.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code Below code. Use getItems() instead of getItemsCollection() function. and also check Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item is extended or not.

```
$customer_email = 'rasd@gmail.com';
$customer_detail = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer_detail->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer_detail->loadByEmail($customer_email);

$storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())->getStoreIds();
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)->loadByCustomer($customer_detail);
if ($quote) {

    $productsResult = array();
    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) { 

        $product = $item->getProduct(); 
        $productsResult[] = array(// Basic product data
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'sku' => $product->getSku(),
            'name' => $product->getName(),
            'set' => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
            'type' => $product->getTypeId(),
            'category_ids' => $product->getCategoryIds(),
            'website_ids' => $product->getWebsiteIds()
        );
    }
    return $productsResult;
}
```

Comment: I included the code for extend quote model 'require_once('Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php');' in my controller file. but i still get empty array.

Comment: extend this file'require_once('Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php');'

Comment: Sorry Empty array only

Comment: did you get $quote properly means is empty or array.

Comment: $productsResult returns as an empty array.

Comment: $quote->getAllItems() - returns an empty array i think.

Comment: may be this is wrong $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)->loadByCustomer($customer_detail); 
try this one $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer_detail);

Comment: if this $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer_detail);  line is not workin then try load customer by id instead of email id

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    require_once('app/Mage.php');
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();

    $customerId = 1; // your customer ID
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
        ->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)
        ->loadByCustomer($customer);

    if ($quote) {
        $collection = $quote->getItemsCollection();
        if ($collection->count() > 0) {
            foreach( $collection as $item ) {
                echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
                echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
                echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
                echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
                echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
                echo "<br />";

            }
        }
    }

?>
```